# Detecting Circular Dependencies

Tags: java, recursion, breadth-first-search

Given a dependency tree of "Scenarios", I'm calculating the "weight" of each scenario branch.

*I need to detect circular dependencies (scenario1 -> scenario2 -> scenario3 -> scenario1).*

I'm currently doing a breadth-first search and passing a list down the recursion chain, however I'm not able to detect a circular dependency.

Each iteration I add the current scenario (String) to the `List` and then check `dependsOnScenarios` (an array of scenario names).

I should be just checking if a string is contained within a list of Strings but this scenario never catches it.

Am I adding to/checking the List at the wrong time?

**Edit:**

`allScenarios` is: a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Scenario>`

`dependsOnScenarios` is a `String[]` and a property of `Scenario`

`name` is a String and a property of `Scenario`

`getWeight` is initially called with an empty list:

`s.priority = getWeight(s, new ArrayList<String>())+1;`

**Input:**

```
Scenario g1=new Scenario("Scenario1" , null);
Scenario g2=new Scenario("Scenario2" , new String[]{"Scenario4"});
Scenario g3=new Scenario("Scenario3" , new String[]{"Scenario1","Scenario2"});
Scenario g4=new Scenario("Scenario4" , new String[]{"Scenario3"});
```

**Code:**

```
private static int getWeight(Scenario scenario, List<String> visited) throws Exception{
  int numDep = 0;         
  visited.add(scenario.name);  
  if(scenario.dependsOnScenarios != null){          
      for(String dependency:scenario.dependsOnScenarios) {
           if(visited.contains(dependency)){
                 throw new Exception("Circular Reference: "+dependency+" has already occured");
           }
           return scenario.dependsOnScenarios.length + getWeight(allScenarios.get(dependency),visited);
      }
  }
  return numDep;
}
```

Comment: Debug the simplest case which fails.

Comment: What type is "allScenarios"?

Comment: @JanTheGun edited for this

Comment: maybe the problem is that you return upon hitting the first dependency? so you don't finish the loop..

Comment: also, use a Set not a List, will be faster..

Comment: How does the code look like when you pass your Input to the getWeight method? Where is "visited" located?

Comment: @JanTheGun it's initally called with an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was returning from the loop before I could evaluate and check the entire list. I needed to be using an additional loop to check everything fully fist.

```
private static int getWeight(Scenario scenario, List<String> visited) throws Exception{
  int numDep = 0;
  visited.add(scenario.name);
  if(scenario.dependsOnScenarios != null){
      for(String dependency:scenario.dependsOnScenarios) {
          if(visited.contains(dependency)){
             throw new Exception("Circular Reference: "+String.join("->",visited)+"->"+dependency);
          }
      }
      for(String dependency:scenario.dependsOnScenarios) {              
          return scenario.dependsOnScenarios.length + getWeight(allScenarios.get(dependency),visited);
      }
  }
  return numDep;
}
```